# For skinning is it better to make parent or to add modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, rigging, parent

Hello the community,

I'm learning alone in selftaught mode. 
My purpose is not to do animation but to have stable printable figurine.
I want to change the legs positions of my damselfly.

I did some test to catch how to rig a cylinder. And my conclusion is that if I use as in the tutorial the parenting function Crtl-P, then I get a complex relationship hard to remove or apply. And I get fuzzy when having to manage vertex groups. This is why I believe the result is easyer to manage if I just add the armature as a modifier of the mesh.

Would it be an expert in this place to understand and provide advice? [image: Testing ways of skinning-rigging]

Comment: When you use ctrl-P with armature deform, it's just like a macro: it parents the object, and it adds the modifier.  It's exactly the same as ctrl-p make parent and creating the modifier yourself.  Parenting the mesh to the armature isn't necessary unless you're going to do something weird, so feel free to just use the modifier if that makes you more comfortable.

Comment: Thx for this answer. Clear.